# rearranging columns having same names to one column by pivoting data in data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with following structure:

```
ID Material Description color size dim color size dim Tech
1  xcv456    Rubber       101   s   32  102    m   34  elastic
```

I want to convert this into:

```
ID Material Description color size dim tech
1  xcv456   Rubber       101   s    32  elastic
1  xcv456   Rubber       102   m    34  elastic
```

I have this file with 5 rows and 5414 columns, so i am trying to automate the process wherein my program would detect redundant columns and convert them to required output format. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#mask for all duplicates columns
m = df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)
#set index with not dupe columns
df = df.set_index(df.columns[~m].tolist())
#count dupes for MultiIndex
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = [df.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
#reshape and remove 4 level, because 4 non dupe columns
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=4, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID Material Description     Tech  color  dim size
0   1   xcv456      Rubber  elastic    101   32    s
1   1   xcv456      Rubber  elastic    102   34    m
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID Material Description  color size  dim  color size  dim      Tech
0   1   xcv456      Rubber    101    s   32    102    m   34   elastic
1   2   xcv457     Rubber1    101    s   37    108    m   55  elastic2

#mask for all duplicates columns
m = df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)
#set index with not dupe columns
df = df.set_index(df.columns[~m].tolist())
#count dupes for MultiIndex
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = [df.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=4, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID Material Description      Tech  color  dim size
0   1   xcv456      Rubber   elastic    101   32    s
1   1   xcv456      Rubber   elastic    102   34    m
2   2   xcv457     Rubber1  elastic2    101   37    s
3   2   xcv457     Rubber1  elastic2    108   55    m
```

Comment: @Bharathshetty - Thank you

Comment: I got empty rows. Oh now I see it maybe because I used pd.read_clipboard duplicate columns added with .1 at the end sorry my bad

Comment: Yes. I was thinking it would not work. Well I think I shld post a question to get rid of that .

Answer (score 1):

Need A little bit process before using `pd.wide_to_Long`

```
hh=pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns=hh+hh.groupby(hh).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
pd.wide_to_long(df,['color','size','dim'],i=['ID1','Material1','Description1','Tech1'],j='drop').reset_index().drop('drop',1
                                                                                                                )
Out[556]: 
   ID1 Material1 Description1    Tech1  color size  dim
0    1    xcv456       Rubber  elastic    101    s   32
1    1    xcv456       Rubber  elastic    102    m   34
```